# What is the correct procedure for creating multi-instances and websites?

Tags: multi-sites, 10

I have installed Drupal 10 and it is working with no issues. I can create my first multi-instance with a single website with no issues.

The problem I have is when I create my second website in the default instance; all of the links in the second website point back to the first website by default. I am assuming the method I am using to create Drupal 8 websites is not the same as it is now in Drupal 10.

Can anyone give me some insight on how to create websites in Drupal 10?  I am sure the way I create them is what is causing the issue, so I am wondering if someone can tell me how to create two sites under the same instance.

This is of how I am doing it now.

1. Copy the default folder in Drupal 10 and rename to your new site
2. On the database server and copy the Drupal 10 database for the site and create a user for it
3. Give permissions to user
4. Go back to web environment
5. Change the current directory to */www/webservices/drupal10/sites/newsite*
6. Edit the *settings.php* file to change the connection information
7. Edit the */www/webservices/drupal10/sites.php* to add a new line for `$sites`
8. Create a symbolic link in */www/webservices* that goes to *drupal10*
9. Check the browser

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [documented procedures for installing multisites](https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/multisite-drupal).